# How can I check compilation errors in python?

Tags: python, compilation

```
#!/usr/bin/python  
str = "this"  
if(1):  
  print "Hi"  
else:  
  print str.any_random_function()
```

This doesn't fail when I run the program. I tried py_compile but that didn't indicate the error in the `else` loop either. Now how can I compile the program and detect errors reliably in python code?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to do that in python. Methods can be dinamically added, the exception captured or the __getattr__ method overloaded. In any of those cases, your error will totally depend or runtime information.

Comment: Actually, this particular example should be caught by pylint.

Comment: It doesn't fail because it's not wrong.  Your module could be imported in a context where `any_random_function` is properly defined for the built-in string class.

Answer (score 9):

I think your best bet would be [pylint](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pylint).

Answer (score 4):

Python is a dynamic language, so you can't simply check for compiling errors like in static languages (C/C++/Java). If you assign `str.any_random_function`, the above code would be correct (okay that's a bad example...).

I'd suggest you to use [PyDev for Eclipse](http://pydev.org/) which automatically finds many common problems in your code, like missing functions/modules etc. It also supports [pylint](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pylint) (optional).

Comment: It's easy for a random keystore to add a character to a function call. So is it suggested to run pylint through the entire codebase or have unit tests and 100% code coverage to catch that wrong function call?

Thanks for replies.

Comment: It takes some time to get used to pylint, and it may produce lots of (useless) messages if not configured correctly. Anyway, as a good software engineer you should always target 100% code coverage using unit tests. The advantage is that they can be run (semi-)automatically - pylint messages must be interpreted by humans.

Answer (score 0):

result_str="";
for row in range(0,7):
for column in range(0,7):
if (column == 1 or column == 5 or (row == 2 and (column == 2 or column == 4)) or (row == 3 and column == 3)):
result_str=result_str+"* "
else:
result_str=result_str+"  "
result_str=result_str+"\n"
print(result_str);

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Also, because Python is indentation-sensitive, you need to fix the formatting of your post, by using this info https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hello, please don't just submit code in your answer(s), add some details as to why you think this is the optimal solution.